# How to remove special characters from the XML feed in android?

Tags: android

I'm receiving XML feed from a server and sometimes there are some special characteres in the feedsa. How can I remove special symbols?

I'm trying with using `ArrayList`. It's working but I need to use it in with String. How can I do this?

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing some code and a specific problem.

Comment: show us some example please so we can help u better

Answer (score 0):

getXMLString(parsingStr) //convert your special char here

```
public static String getXMLString(String str)
    {
        if(str.contains("&"))
        {
            str = str.replace("&", "&amp;");
        }else if (str.contains("<"))
        {
            str = str.replace("<", "&lt;");
        }else if (str.contains(">"))
        {
            str = str.replace(">", "&gt;");
        }else if (str.contains("'"))
        {
            str = str.replace("'", "&apos;");
        }else if (str.contains("\""))
        {
            str = str.replace("\"", "&quot;");
        }

        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code it is as above but dont need all the if statements so:

```
public static String getXMLString(String content) {
    content = content.replace("&", "&amp");
    content = content.replace("<", "&lt;");
    content = content.replace(">", "&gt;");
    content = content.replace("'", "&apos;");
    content = content.replace("\"", "&quot;");
    return content;
}
```